# Using 'generic' virtual for mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to convert _id variable as id.

So i want to add virtual 'id' field to all the schema i am going to create, that will return the value of '_id' whenever i access 'id' field of the model.

from the documentation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html
i found that, first i have to create schema then apply the virtual 'id' field individually.

I want to simply add virtual field to the base `mongoose.Schema` and then whenever i will create a new schema, that all will have virtual field without any manual effort on each of the individual schema.

EDIT :

i am also using Backbone.Model and i have created an 'id' field for each model. If i get the simply use id in the front end codes, i get the error that id field not exists. BUT when i set idAttribute as '_id' to each model then everything goes OK. That means backbone model want to have _id, and the reason behind mongoose schema have _id not id. So can i interpret that,  mongoose does not automatically add virtual id mapped to _id? Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For backbone, "id" is it's default idAttribute name, so just don't add any code there and everything will work as intended.

For mongoose, the answer boils down to "it's complicated", but the main points are:

- By default mongoose will give each schema a virtual called "id" which will be the document's _id as a string
- However, by default `.toJSON` doesn't include virtuals, so when you send a mongoose document to backbone in the browser, it gets just "_id" and not "id"
- to quickly get a JSON representation including the virtuals, use `myModelInstance.toJSON({virtuals: true})`. You'll get both "_id" and "id"
- You need to read up on the [transform options for toObject and toJSON](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) to get a full picture of what you can do and how, but the gist is (based on examples straight from the docs)

---

```
// specify the transform schema option
if (!schema.options.toJSON) schema.options.toJSON = {};
schema.options.toJSON.transform = function (doc, ret, options) {
  // remove the _id of every document before returning the result
  delete ret._id;
}
schema.options.toJSON.virtuals = true;
```